# how to get last ten item with REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, rest

I need to get the last ten created item from my list ; I used TOP in my query but this it doesn't work , still give me all items without filtering :
this is my query :

```
var queryGet= "?$filter=Title ne 'reply'&top=3"
```

any ideas.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For listing item in a particular order you should use `orderby` in the URL

```
var queryGet = "?filter=Title ne 'reply'&$top=10&$orderby=Created desc"
```

Comment: it still give me all items , the top=10 doesnt work

Comment: sorry a typo.. use `$top`. See my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items?$top=10&$select=Title&$orderby=Title desc
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit so the person asking the question gets the knowledge behind it.

Comment: This doesn't add anything, as the accepted answer already mentioned the `$orderby` parameter.